# blocked css stylesheet due to MIME type ("text/html") mismatch

Tags: css, asp.net-core, mime-types

I have a Net Core 3.1 with Angular project, and I want to load a stylessheet on one of my pages. However, it refuses to load, giving the error:

```
The resource from was blocked due to MIME type ("text/html") mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

My stylessheet is called like this:

```
<link href="~\lib\custum\css\admin\adminstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

My `startup.cs` includes `app.UseStaticFiles();`

How can this be resolved?

Solution:

`<link href="~/lib/custum/css/admin/adminstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in end worked, after I fixed my `@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialView.cshtml")` with the correct file extension, the `.cshtml`.

Comment: Hi @CMorgan, Did you try to change the reference like: `<link href="~\lib\custum\css\admin\adminstyles.css" type="text/css" />
`?

Comment: @Rena thanks for the reply. First, I changed the "\" into "/". Second, I found that my `@await Html.PartialAsync()` didn't have the file extension of the partial view. Once I fixed this, it worked.